# Batch File to Replace string in file name and extension

Tags: batch, rename

I'm trying to write a simple, small and flexible batch file that is easy to modify for different fabricators that will run through a list of gerber files made in Proteus and rename them appropriately.

This set is for Seeed Studio.

The problem I'm having is that only the extension is being corrected, I need the whole string replaced.

i.e "Circuit  - CADCAM Bottom Copper.TXT" becomes "Circuit.GBL" etc.

Currently "Circuit  - CADCAM Bottom Copper.TXT" becomes "Circuit  - CADCAM Bottom Copper.GBL"

Thanks for the help,

Haydan

```
@echo off
Setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

REM Check all files are present and rename

set MISSING=0
call :CheckFile " - CADCAM Bottom Copper.TXT", ".GBL"
call :CheckFile " - CADCAM Bottom Copper", "-"
call :CheckFile " - CADCAM Bottom Silk Screen.TXT", ".GBO"
call :CheckFile " - CADCAM Bottom Solder Resist.TXT", ".GBS"
call :CheckFile " - CADCAM Drill.TXT", ".TXT"
call :CheckFile " - CADCAM Mechanical 1.TXT", ".GKO"
call :CheckFile " - CADCAM Top Copper.TXT", ".GTL"
call :CheckFile " - CADCAM Top Silk Screen.TXT", ".GTO"
call :CheckFile " - CADCAM Top Solder Resist.TXT", ".GTS"
REM if exist "Internal Plane 1.ger" call :CheckFile "Internal Plane 2.ger", ""

if %MISSING% EQU 0 (
    echo Success - all files found!
    pause
    goto :eof
) else (
    echo %MISSING% file^(s^) missing.
    pause
    goto :eof
)
REM Rename as found or flag erro

:CheckFile
if not exist *%1 (
    echo ERROR: Missing %1!
    set /a MISSING=%MISSING% + 1
) else (
    echo %1
    echo %2
    ren *%1 *%2
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next `:CheckFile` procedure should do the job:

```
:CheckFile
set "_string=%~1"
if not exist *%1 (
    echo ERROR: Missing %1!
    set /a MISSING+=1
) else (
    for /F "delims=" %%G in ('dir /B "*%~1"') do (
        set "_fileA=%%~G"
        set "_fileB=!_fileA:%_string%=!"
        rem next `rename` command is merely ECHOed for debugging purposes
        ECHO ren "%%~G" "!_fileB!%~2"
    )
)
goto :eof
```

**Note**: `rename` command is merely ECHOed for debugging purposes in above code snippet; remove leading `ECHO` (use `ren "%%~G" "!_fileB!%~2"`) no sooner than debugged!

**Output**:

```
==> D:\bat\SU\1119379.bat
ren "Circ #2 - CADCAM Bottom Copper.TXT" "Circ #2.GBL"
ren "Circuit - CADCAM Bottom Copper.TXT" "Circuit.GBL"
ren "Circuit - CADCAM Bottom Copper" "Circuit-"
ERROR: Missing " - CADCAM Bottom Silk Screen.TXT"
ERROR: Missing " - CADCAM Bottom Solder Resist.TXT"
ERROR: Missing " - CADCAM Drill.TXT"
ERROR: Missing " - CADCAM Mechanical 1.TXT"
ERROR: Missing " - CADCAM Top Copper.TXT"
ERROR: Missing " - CADCAM Top Silk Screen.TXT"
ERROR: Missing " - CADCAM Top Solder Resist.TXT"
7 file(s) missing.
Press any key to continue . . .
```

**Resources** (required reading, incomplete):

- (command reference) [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- (additional particularities) [Windows CMD Shell Command Line Syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html)
- (`%~G`, `%~1` etc. special page) [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)
- (`set "_fileB=!_fileA:%_string%=!"` etc.) [Variable Edit/Replace](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html)